# Backbone: avoid view render if the model was changed from the same view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have the following structure created with Backbone. Each view listen the same model. Each view can update it. How can I to avoid render method call of the view that caused
model update?

```
var MyView1 = Backbone.View({
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render)
  },
  events: {
    'click' : 'set'
  },
  render: function() {
    return this
  },
  set: function (){
    this.model.set('property1', 'value')
  }
})

var MyView2 = Backbone.View({
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render)
  },
  events: {
    'click' : 'set'
  },
  render: function() {
    return this
  },
  set: function (){
    this.model.set('property1', 'value')
  }
})

var model = new Backbone.Model
var view1 = new MyView1({model: model})
var view2 = new MyView2({model: model})
```

I expect:

click on view1 -> model.set() -> only view2's render method should be called

From my WinForms experience now I'm passing view's cid as sender with options and check it on render but it seems little ugly.

Comment: don't think there is any other method but to send view information in options. you could send the view in options itself and check it in render. - one small change you could do to keep your render method clean is to bind 'change' event to an intermediate method where you check whether to call render or not.

Comment: Does it cause a visual or UX problem when both views render in response to the change? If not, then the cleanest code is to just let it happen :)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `mode.set` with the option `{silent: true}` to avoid that the views render method is executed. E.g.:

```
this.model.set({'property1', 'value'}, {silent: true});
```

But also note that in general this is not recommended:

> Generally speaking, when calling a function that emits an event
>   (model.set, collection.add, and so on...), if you'd like to prevent
>   the event from being triggered, you may pass {silent: true} as an
>   option. Note that this is rarely, perhaps even never, a good idea.
>   Passing through a specific flag in the options for your event callback
>   to look at, and choose to ignore, will usually work out better.

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog